# closures in javascript understanding example

Tags: javascript, closures

```
function setupSomeGlobals() {
    // Local variable that ends up within closure

    var num = 666;
    // Store some references to functions as global variables
    gAlertNumber = function() {console.log(1); alert(num); }
    gIncreaseNumber = function() { num++; }
    gSetNumber = function(x) { num = x; }
}
```

how can I accesss here gAlertNumber method?

**update:** this code is the Example 4 in an answer on [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/111111/1176601)

Comment: You cannot access it outside the function because it is not in scope, and you have no accessible reference to it

Comment: @Jeffman, @musefan: `gAlertNumber` is a global variable. Why you think it isn't accessible outside of `setupSomeGlobals`? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j5yTn/)

Comment: That's a bad way to initialize globals, and you really shouldn't be using global variables anyway. In "strict" mode it'd be an error.

Comment: use `window.gAlertNumber = ...;` for explicit creation of global objects that works in strict mode as well. better yet, wrap your code into a module to later access it simply by `window.MyModule.alertNumber();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're in a web browser, you have to execute `setupSomeGlobal()` first.
Then your non-declared handler variables g... will be created under the global object `window` and you'll be able to execute `gAlertNumber()` from anywhere in your page.

You could execute `setupSomeGlobal()` in the body's `onload` :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function setupSomeGlobals() {
                // Local variable that ends up within closure

                var num = 666;
                // Store some references to functions as global variables
                gAlertNumber = function() {console.log(1); alert(num); }
                gIncreaseNumber = function() { num++; }
                gSetNumber = function(x) { num = x; }
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="setupSomeGlobals();">
        <input type="button" value="Show me more or less the number of the beast" onclick="gAlertNumber();"
    </body>
</html>
```

That said, your method of setting up "global" functions isn't very pretty.
I quite like the pattern described [here](http://www.dustindiaz.com/javascript-private-public-privileged/) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example,

```
(function() {
   console.log(1);
   // Local variable that ends up within closure
   var num = 666;
   var sayAlert = function() { console.log(num); }
   num++;
   return sayAlert();
})();
```

This will call immediately after definition.

So with your code,

```
function setupSomeGlobals() {

  var num = 666;
  // Store some references to functions as global variables
  gAlertNumber = function() {console.log(1); alert(num); }
  gIncreaseNumber = function() { num++; }
  gSetNumber = function(x) { num = x; }

  gAlertNumber();

}
setupSomeGlobals();
```

Here you can call the child function `gAlertNumber()` inside your parent function `setupSomeGlobals()` and you cannot access it outside the parent function.

But you can call this after calling parent function, that means don't call the `gAlertNumber()` inside parent function. call it after calling parent like,

```
function setupSomeGlobals() {
    // Local variable that ends up within closure
    var num = 666;
    // Store some references to functions as global variables
    gAlertNumber = function() {console.log(1); alert(num); }
    gIncreaseNumber = function() { num++; }
    gSetNumber = function(x) { num = x; }
}

setupSomeGlobals();
gAlertNumber();
```

Comment: i don't get i got an example from the second answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1 there is no var there

Comment: and if we write   'gAlertNumber(); like u suggested what can we do with
 gIncreaseNumber ?

Comment: @Pointy You mean for what reason?

Comment: Note that the second example is not [strict javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode).

Comment: I think there is no need to use ``var`` and if you are used with ``var`` also you can't call it outside.

Comment: so help to see how can we use this 3  methods to understand closure instead of arguing about using or not using var

Comment: @devo well I hadn't really understood what the OP is doing (which probably means I need my head examined, given the name of the function).

Comment: I would +1 if you just answered the question with the 3rd example without metaphysical introduction - that is exactly how to access `gAlertNumber` method.

Answer (score 0):

Return an object from setSomeGlobals() that contains the three methods. Through this object you will be able to access the functions of interest and manipulate num and keep its state, but you will not be able to access num directly. This is known as the module pattern, an application of closure.

Answer (score 0):

Well this will work in browser

gAlertNumber is considered being window property.. It would be the same as calling

```
  window.gAlertNumber()
```

so inside your *setSomeGlobals* you assign function object to the undefined window property. Than you *close* the local variable *num* inside that object which is already created inside *window* object. Thus you can access it from window scope.